# Bypassing Angular Routing on <a> tags

Tags: angularjs

After searching long and far, I have not been able to determine how to hit the external routes outside of my angular app using a tags. I need links to go to other places that my server serves up. For example,

```
<a href="/login", target="_self">Login</a>
```

does not render the non-angular page that I want from the server. It just takes me back to the same place. However, it is of note that the URL is actually hit, but Angular then immediately re-renders the page. The "_self" target trick has worked in the past, but I'm not sure why it's not working now.

Does anyone have any advice here?

**HTML Markup:**

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-view>
      //angular templates, angular stuff, etc... // Works fine
    </div>
     <a href="/login", target="_self">Login</a> // Doesn't render page
</div>
```

**Angular code:**

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/', {templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html',   controller: 'DashboardController'}).
      when('/learn', {templateUrl: 'templates/learn.html',   controller: 'LearnController'}).
      when('/draft', {templateUrl: 'templates/draft.html',   controller: 'DraftController'}).

      otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your external routes do not require any AngularJS magic, just put your links outside of of the div you're using to declare your AngularJS app.

Comment: I just did and it did work. Could you please provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: What ended up happening was that I had TWO ng-views and it was really screwing things up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah that'll do it! No problem Spencer :)